# POWER BI Creating new query out of existing one using range of columns

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Trying to create a new query from the existing "Master" Query using below formula:

let
 Source = Table.SelectColumns('Original Source Name',{'Column Name','Column Name2'})
 in
 Source

which works fine, however I am looking to see if there is any other formula which would do the same but in a way that it will create the new query with a range of columns , for example Column 30- 67 ( in this case when the original Excel file is updated, inserting a column in this range it would automatically update in the PBI too when refreshed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possible way. If you start with this table, named Table1:

[image]

You can reference it in a new query like this:

```
let
Source = Table.SelectColumns(Table1, List.Range(Table.ColumnNames(Table1), 2, 3))
in
Source
```

...to get this:

[image]

The formula selects a range of columns from the table starting at the column at index position 2, and spanning 3 columns. (The index starts with 0.) For columns 30-67, you would change the 2 to 31 and the 3 to 37. You would change Table1 to your Original Source Name as well.

See these links for more info on [List.Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/m/list-range) and [Table.ColumnNames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/m/table-columnnames).